# How to group by & combine serial number and ID while summing packaged and damaged amount?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0TgV.png)

This is an example of the table. I want to combine the Serial number and ID if they have the same value and sum the packaged and damaged amount. I've tried a couple of queries.

```
SELECT * FROM InventoryHistory ih
JOIN 
 (
   SELECT SerialNumber, 
          ID, 
          SUM(PackagedAmount) AS pa, 
          SUM(DamagedAmount AS am
   FROM InventoryHistory 
   GROUP BY SerialNumber, ID
 ) ttl 
ON SerialNumber = ih.SerialNumber AND ttl.ID = ih.ID)
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of your input table and the expected output as a *tabular text*, clarify what you are trying to do, and what is the problem with your posted query.

Answer (score 0):

In the future please write the Database System you are using.

In SQL Server with Transact SQL this will work:

```
Select 
Name
, ID
, SerialNumber
, sum(PackagedAmount) as SumPackagedAmount
, sum(DamagedAmount ) as SumDamagedAmount 
From InventoryHistory 
group by 
Name
, ID
, SerialNumber
```

I assumed, that if ID and Serial are the same, the Name will also be the same.

Also check out this for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the typo in your question (missing ')' after the word DamagedAmount )...

If you just want the sum of the columns by SerialNumber and ID then you dont need the outer query at all. The following should give you what you want.

```
SELECT SerialNumber, 
          ID, 
          SUM(PackagedAmount) AS pa, 
          SUM(DamagedAmount) AS am
   FROM InventoryHistory 
   GROUP BY SerialNumber, ID
   WHERE ID = @ID
```

If you want all the detail rows **and** the sum on **every** row then you can do that using windowed functions, like this.

```
SELECT SerialNumber, ID, PackagedAmount, DamagedAmount 
          SUM(PackagedAmount) OVER(PARITION BY SerialNumber, ID) AS pa, 
          SUM(DamagedAmount) OVER(PARITION BY SerialNumber, ID) AS am
   FROM InventoryHistory 
   WHERE ID = @ID
```

(note we do not group using this method as the window function does the goruping)

If this does not help, please post a sample of data (as formatted text) and the expected outcome based on the sample data. Explain what does not work, what errors are you getting it any etc.